# HTTP POST very slow with timeouts on IIS (.NET Core)

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core

I'm trying to put recaptcha on my webite, (written in .NET Core 2.0) in order to prevent spam.

It seems to be working seamlessly on my local IIS Express, but when I try to do the post on the production IIS it just seems to time out. I debugged it and it blows on an http post:

```
_response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Uri, content);
```

I declared the _Response as:

```
private HttpResponseMessage _response;
```

Since it works as expected on ISS Express, I think it may be an IIS configuration issue (that works locally on my machine).

Comment: Can you confirm that the calling method (All the way down to the action), is async and you are not doing a .Wait() or .Result() anywhere along the chain? This could be a deadlock scenario given it's dying on an async method.

Comment: Why would you even want to declare HttpResponseMessage as a member in the first place? Usually you operate on it and then dispose it (its disposable, contains reference to `HttpContent` which holds a Stream Reference). Show more code invovled in that, we can't do fortune telling. Also exception on timeout would be useful

Comment: Check IIS log files to see what IIS thought about the requests (not just the POST). Without that, it is pointless to guess the culprit.